# can ultralytics(YOLOv8) load model weight from byte array

Tags: yolov8

Normally `ultralytics`(`YOLOv8`) loads model weight this way:

```
YOLO('./model.pt')
```

Now we have a requirement that encrypt `.pt` file firstly, and then decrypt the file before load model. The decrypted data is byte array or `io.BytesIO`, is there a way to load the momery data directly? We don't want to write the decrypted data into a file again.